# hide things while loading via jquery doesnt work propper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, loading

on my site http://boxcomp.111mb.de/luxus/html9

im using jquery to hide the content until its loaded and to fade it in when its loaded. this way it looks much cleaner and smoother. Im loading the content with AJAX. The problem is, that it doesnt work propper. when the connection is slow, the content appears before its loaded. that shouldnt be the case. here is the code that im using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home').click(function() {
        $('#content-shown , #pics').animate({opacity: 0}, 250, function() {
            $('.content-loading').fadeIn(250, function() {
                $('#navigation_all , #content-shown').css("height", "1500px");
                $('#pics').load('content.html #home-bild').animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
                $('#content-shown').load('content.html #home', function() {
                    $('.content-loading').fadeOut(250, function() {
                        $('#content-shown').animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});​
</script>
```

when an object is clicked, i fade out the actual content, fade in a "please wait" text (.loading) while the content is loading (but invisible) then when the content is loaded, the .loading fades out and the content fades in. but sometimes it apears before everything is fully loaded.

how can i make sure it fades in when its loaded??

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using window.onload = function(){...}   ???

Comment: isnt there a way to add a function that stops the next from executing before its done?? that would probably solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see is that in this line:

```
$('#pics').load('content.html #home-bild').animate({opacity:1},250);
```

You may need to move the `animate` function to the load's callback function, rather than just chaining it. Example:

```
$('#pics').load('content.html #home-bild', function(){
  $('#pics').animate({opacity:1},250)
});
```

or use `opacity:'show'` instead:

```
 $('#pics').load('content.html #home-bild', function(){
      $('#pics').animate({opacity:'show'},250)
    });
```

Comment: thats not the problem. i have two divs that are loaded with new content. the first is #pics, the second one is #content-shown. #content-shown has also the described problem and the code to animate is in the callback fuction as you said.

Comment: @user1836966 How about waiting for one before executing the next? You could add a callback function to `animate` using `complete` that will start the next load (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)